# Landing page forms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part, list-form

I'm working on a new SharePoint public-facing website for my company, and need to replicate a feature of our current site, which we call 'landing pages'.

The concept is that my marketing team can create a form, with a short url, which can be emailed to prospects or customers depending on the current marketing campaign.

The form would ask the typical info, such as first name, last name, organization, address (if the person completing our forms want a demo CD of our product), etc. Once the user submits the form, we'd want to store the information in SharePoint, and execute custom code on the back end to have our CRM (NetSuite) updated with brief tracking information.

The current system was a custom built .NET solution (written by me), but we're looking for a more established, 3rd party/commercial solution now, one that's proven to work with SharePoint Server 2010 and comes with good recommendations.

I found one possible solution, [SharePoint FormWebpart](http://sharepointformwebpart.com/) which looks good, albeit a little on the expensive side. Has anyone used this? Are there any alternative solutions for what I'm describing above?

Any advice would be appreciated :)

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you want to save the info on sharepoint and also on crm or just in crm.

If you want to do it in both:
1.   You need to create a custom content type with the fields you need.
2.   You create a list that inherits from the content type
3.   With Sharepoint Designer you can customize the forms to add or edit fields.

http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/mpoole/archive/2011/01/13/sharepoint-2010-customlistforms-by-guest-writer-sarah-whitehouse.aspx

1. Create a feature with an event receiver for the item adding event, in the item_adding you can detect the list, and then write your custom code to create what you need in the CRM
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx

If you dont want to save any info on a sharepoint list, just in the crm.
1.  Create a webpart with the form and create your own code, just as a normal asp.net web application.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Luis. I'll look into this, but we are looking for a 3rd party solution, rather than a custom solution. My original question wasn't clear in that, so I apologize for that, and I'll update it now to specify a 3rd party, commercial solution.

Comment: As an update, I think I have a solution that will work for my needs. Using a list I can display the NewForm.aspx page for the list in an iFrame (either as a Page Viewer web part, or HTML Form webpart) adding some CSS to the .aspx page to remove the ribbon, and the "source=/myprocessingscript.aspx" to the URL used by the iFrame. e.g. <iframe src='/Lists/myLandingPageList/NewForm.aspx?source=/muprocessingscript.aspx'